# How can I update_post_meta outside post from outside of the post with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am building a plugin for my website and it has a checkbox inside the custom meta box and when the checkbox is unchecked then Button1 will be displayed and if it is checked button2 will be displayed. Thats for the authors. So, I have a button on the post list too for each of the posts. So, with ajax I want to check the checkbox on clicking the button that I have made on the post list with the custom column and update the post meta too from unchecked to checked.

```
function cruiser_topic_pick_box_callback( $post ) {
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
$topic_checkbox_value = ( isset( $meta['topic_checkbox_value'][0] ) &&  '1' === $meta['topic_checkbox_value'][0] ) ? 1 : 0;
wp_nonce_field( 'topic_checkbox_value', 'topic_checkbox_value' ); 

echo'<input type="checkbox" name="topic_checkbox_value" id="topic_checkbox_value-' . $post->ID . '" value="1" ' . checked( $topic_checkbox_value, 1 ) . ' style="display: none;"/>'

if( $topic_checkbox_value  == 0){
    echo '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="click-btn" onclick="checkedFunction(' . $post->ID .')">Pick</button>';
}
else {
    echo '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Picked</button>';

}
}

function cruiser_save_topic_writer( $post_id )
{

$topic_checkbox_value = ( isset( $_POST['topic_checkbox_value'] ) && '1' === $_POST['topic_checkbox_value'] ) ? 1 : 0;
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'topic_checkbox_value', esc_attr( $topic_checkbox_value ) );

}
```

So, its already working inside the post but there is button outside the post on custom columns. So, when the user clicks the button on the custom columns then it automatically should change the checkbox to be checked. By default, the checkbox will be unchecked.

What I really want is when the user clicks the button on the custom columns then the checkbox will be checked inside the post and as a result the text of the Button1 will change to button2.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){         
    jQuery('#content').on('click', '.mycheckbox', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_id = jQuery(this).data( 'id' );   
        var mycheckbox_id = jQuery(this).val(); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            url  : ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'update_post_topic_writer',
                post_id : post_id,
                mycheckbox_id : mycheckbox_id 
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });          
    });     
});
```

PHP

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_post_topic_writer', 'update_post_topic_writer' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_post_topic_writer', 'update_post_topic_writer' );

    function update_post_topic_writer() {


        if ( isset($_POST) ) {

            $mycheckbox_id = $_POST['mycheckbox_id'];
            $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'topic_checkbox_value', esc_attr( $mycheckbox_id ) );

$return = array(
    'message' => __( 'Saved', 'textdomain' ),
);
wp_send_json_success( $return );

    }
```

Comment: Hey man, really thanks for the reply but it is not working. First thing I got confused with the id and class names. And I can't understand how is the checkbox is checked and since all the post have different checkbox so don't i need to pass the id of the button and the post. I know your answer was relevant but I am little confused as it was not working.